# Assign a datepicker to multiple inputs and allow certain dates to be selectable in each one of them

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to attach a jquery UI datepicker to multiple inputs on the same page. Then I want each datepicker to have certain dates clickable. Seems to work BUT I get the same selectable dates for all the datepickers.

My code is this

**html Example code for 2 fields**

```
<input id="packid17" class="lollydate form_field_style" size="12" data-avdates17="12/01/2012,12/04/2012,12/08/2012,12/11/2012,12/15/2012,12/18/2012,12/22/2012,12/25/2012,12/29/2012,01/01/2013,01/05/2013,01/08/2013,01/12/2013,01/15/2013,01/19/2013,01/22/2013,01/26/2013,01/29/2013,02/02/2013,02/05/2013,02/09/2013,02/12/2013,02/16/2013,02/19/2013,02/23/2013,02/26/2013,03/02/2013,03/05/2013,03/09/2013,03/12/2013,03/16/2013,03/19/2013,03/23/2013,03/26/2013,03/30/2013,04/02/2013,04/03/2013,04/04/2013,04/06/2013,04/09/2013,04/10/2013,04/11/2013,04/13/2013,04/16/2013,04/17/2013,04/18/2013,04/20/2013,04/23/2013,04/24/2013,04/25/2013,04/27/2013,04/30/2013,05/01/2013,05/02/2013,05/04/2013,05/07/2013,05/08/2013,05/09/2013,05/11/2013,05/14/2013,05/15/2013,05/16/2013,05/18/2013,05/21/2013,05/22/2013,05/23/2013,05/25/2013,05/28/2013,05/29/2013,05/30/2013,06/01/2013,06/04/2013,06/05/2013,06/06/2013,06/08/2013,06/11/2013,06/12/2013,06/13/2013,06/15/2013,06/18/2013,06/19/2013,06/20/2013,06/22/2013,06/25/2013,06/26/2013,06/27/2013,06/29/2013,07/02/2013,07/03/2013,07/04/2013,07/06/2013,07/09/2013,07/10/2013,07/11/2013,07/13/2013,07/16/2013,07/17/2013,07/18/2013,07/20/2013,07/23/2013,07/24/2013,07/25/2013,07/27/2013,07/30/2013,07/31/2013,08/01/2013,08/03/2013,08/06/2013,08/07/2013,08/08/2013,08/10/2013,08/13/2013,08/14/2013,08/15/2013,08/17/2013,08/20/2013,08/21/2013,08/22/2013,08/24/2013,08/27/2013,08/28/2013,08/29/2013,08/31/2013,09/03/2013,09/04/2013,09/05/2013,09/07/2013,09/10/2013,09/11/2013,09/12/2013,09/14/2013,09/17/2013,09/18/2013,09/19/2013,09/21/2013,09/24/2013,09/25/2013,09/26/2013,09/28/2013,10/01/2013,10/02/2013,10/03/2013,10/05/2013,10/08/2013,10/09/2013,10/10/2013,10/12/2013,10/15/2013,10/16/2013,10/17/2013,10/19/2013,10/22/2013,10/23/2013,10/24/2013,10/26/2013,10/29/2013,10/30/2013,10/31/2013,11/02/2013,11/05/2013,11/09/2013,11/12/2013,11/16/2013,11/19/2013,11/23/2013,11/26/2013,11/30/2013" data-packid="17" type="text" name="date" value="">

<input id="packid23" class="lollydate form_field_style" size="12" data-avdates23="04/19/2013,04/22/2013,04/26/2013,04/29/2013,05/03/2013,05/06/2013,05/10/2013,05/13/2013,05/17/2013,05/20/2013,05/24/2013,05/27/2013,05/31/2013,06/03/2013,06/07/2013,06/10/2013,06/14/2013,06/17/2013,06/21/2013,06/24/2013,06/28/2013,07/01/2013,07/05/2013,07/08/2013,07/12/2013,07/15/2013,07/19/2013,07/22/2013,07/26/2013,07/29/2013,08/02/2013,08/05/2013,08/09/2013,08/12/2013,08/16/2013,08/19/2013,08/23/2013,08/26/2013,08/30/2013,09/02/2013,09/06/2013,09/09/2013,09/13/2013,09/16/2013,09/20/2013,09/23/2013,09/27/2013,09/30/2013,10/04/2013,10/07/2013,10/11/2013,10/14/2013,10/18/2013,10/21/2013,10/25/2013" data-packid="23" type="text" name="date" value="">
```

**And my Jquery code is this**

```
(function(){
            var lollydate = $(".lollydate");

            lollydate.each(function(){
                $this = $(this);
                $this.datepicker({
                dateformat:'mm/dd/yy',
                showAnim : 'fold',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                minDate:"-10d",
                maxDate: "+18M",
                beforeShowDay: function(d){
                    var dateid = lollydate.data('packid');
                    //console.log(dateid);
                     var datelist = lollydate.data('avdates'+dateid).split(",");
                    // normalize the date for searching in array
                    var dmy = "";
                    dmy += ("00" + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/";
                    dmy += ("00" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/";
                    dmy += d.getFullYear();
                    if ($.inArray(dmy, datelist) >= 0) {
                        return [true, ""];
                    }
                    else {
                        return [false, ""];
                    }
                }
            });
            }); // end each




        })();
```

Comment: use same `data-` attribute name for each element, no need to increment them just use `data-avdates`. The attribute is unique to each element

Comment: Thank you, I increased everything just in case that was the problem. I'll put the stable data- back in a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what the problem was. I was comparing wrong values.

my date format was not the same in the data-avdates and in the jquery part. So I converted the jquery part like this and its worked perfectly

```
 var dmy = "";
    dmy += ("00" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/";
    dmy += ("00" + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/";
    dmy += d.getFullYear();
```

Thank you all for your super fast help :-)

Comment: Ofourse I am sure there is room for better code here. I am still learning jquery so I guess that there is a cleaner less memory intensed way to do this thing.

Comment: another thing...you can store full array simply using `[]` in `data-` attribute, no need to split to make array `data-avdates="[d1,d2,d3]"`

Comment: Except I think he's writing out those dates as a string from the server side.  He's not using jQuery to populate the data.

Comment: Yes PHP creates this comma separated string for each entry.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming there is more than one element with the `lollydate` class name on your page.  If so, your `lollydate` variable has a length of more than one.

In your `each` loop you are setting the `beforeShowDay` function's variables using `lollydate.data`, which is not precise.  Try changing it to `$(this)`.

```
beforeShowDay: function(d){
    var dateid = $(this).data('packid');
    //console.log(dateid);
     var datelist = $(this).data('avdates'+dateid).split(",");
    // normalize the date for searching in array
    var dmy = "";
    dmy += ("00" + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/";
    dmy += ("00" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/";
    dmy += d.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, datelist) >= 0) {
        return [true, ""];
    }
    else {
        return [false, ""];
    }
}​
```

**Edit**

```
$(function(){
    var lollydate = $(".lollydate");

    lollydate.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.datepicker({
            dateformat:'mm/dd/yy',
            showAnim : 'fold',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            minDate:"-10d",
            maxDate: "+18M",
            beforeShowDay: function(d){
                var dateid = $this.attr('data-packid');
                //console.log(dateid);
                 var datelist = $this.attr('data-avdates').split(",");
                // normalize the date for searching in array
                var dmy = "";
                dmy += ("00" + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/";
                dmy += ("00" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/";
                dmy += d.getFullYear();
                if ($.inArray(dmy, datelist) >= 0) {
                    return [true, ""];
                }
                else {
                    return [false, ""];
                }
            }
        });
    }); // end each
});​
```

In your original script you were not scoping `$this` with `var`, which was causing `$this` to always be the last item in the `each` loop.

You also cannot use `.data("packid")` and instead need to use `.attr("data-packid")`.

Additionally, `$this` needed to be used instead of `lollydate`.

Once those issues were fixed the script should work as intended.  And it probably even allows you to delete the `data-packid` attribute since it doesn't appear to be used anymore.

**Edit 2**

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vYdjD/) if you want to see what I did in action.

*Note*

I had to swap the month and day in the `data-avdates` attribute.  Didn't know which date format you were aiming for.

Comment: I tried that earlier. I have the same problem. The dates that are clickable are not the dates that are set in the data-avadates property of each field.

Comment: Give me one minute.  I'm working on it.  There were quite a few issues with the script you provided.

Comment: Check my answer and please let me know if the code has other issues or it must be refactored somehow.

Comment: Also attr('data-avdates') is the same as data('avdates'). Or its not?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  `$.data(element, key)` does *not* automatically import the data-* elements, but `.data(key)` does.